# Only the iOS 9 can receive the push in the production environment，why

Tags: ios, objective-c, push

The native push problem, iOS9-12 can receive the push in the test environment. Only the iOS 9 can receive the push in the production environment. Does anyone know why?

Comment: have you using Firebase for pushnotification?

Comment: NO，just original push

Comment: Have you done iOS 10 related changes in your code and on server ?

Comment: what you means on server？I have changed in my code,but I don't know what should I do on server